# MongoDB aggregate performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections one is **bids** and another one is **auctions**. I am able to get bid inside customer wise count **bids** collection inside almost one million records. and **auctions** collection have 500k records. I need this same result as quick fetching in mongodb.

this is getting almost 29 seconds for response time. but i need quick time to get response

```
{ $match: { customer: '00000000823026' } },
        { $group: {
                _id: '$auctioncode',
                data: {
                    $last: '$$ROOT'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'auctions',
                let: { auctioncode: '$_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $and: [{ $eq: ['$_id', '$$auctioncode'] }],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
                as: 'auction',
            },
        },
        { $match: { auction: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } } } },
        {
            $addFields: {
                _id: '$data._id',
                auctioncode: '$data.auctioncode',
                amount: '$data.amount',
                customer: '$data.customer',
                customerName: '$data.customerName',
                maxBid: '$data.maxBid',
                stockcode: '$data.stockcode',
                watchlistHidden: '$data.watchlistHidden',
                winner: '$data.winner'
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {
                        // to get only RUNNING auctions in bid history
                        'auction.status': { $ne: 'RUNNING'},
                        // to filter auctions based on status
                        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
        { $sort: { 'auction.enddate': -1 } },
        { $count: 'totalCount'}
```

current result is **totalCount 2640**

how to optimize and need to find a way to performance changes in mongodb

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If all that you require is the count of results, the below code is more optimized.

Index `customer` key for even better execution time.

**Note:** You can make use of `pipeline` method of `$lookup` if you are using MongoDB version >= 5.0 as it makes use if indexes unlike the lower version.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      customer: '00000000823026'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$auctioncode',
      data: {
        $last: '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'auctions',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'auction',
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      // auction: {$ne: []},
      // to get only RUNNING auctions in bid history
      'auction.status': { $ne: 'RUNNING'},
      // to filter auctions based on status
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  // {
  //   $addFields: {  <-- Not Required
  //     _id: '$data._id',
  //     auctioncode: '$data.auctioncode',
  //     amount: '$data.amount',
  //     customer: '$data.customer',
  //     customerName: '$data.customerName',
  //     maxBid: '$data.maxBid',
  //     stockcode: '$data.stockcode',
  //     watchlistHidden: '$data.watchlistHidden',
  //     winner: '$data.winner'
  //   }
  // },
  // { $sort: { 'auction.enddate': -1 } },  <-- Not Required
  { $count: 'totalCount'}
], {
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```